# Not sure how to filter this data

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have Order class as follows.

```
 class Order
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    }
```

In order, I get a list of orders from database and populate in local list that is declared as follows.

```
List<Order> Orders = new List<Order>();
```

I also have a cached list of orders that only contains Order.ID field.

```
List<Guid> CachedOrderIDs;
```

Now I want to modify following query to include Orders that are presnted in CachedOrderIDs.

```
var o = Orders.Where(m => m.ProductID > 200 && m.CategoryID > 500).ToList();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Whoever down voted it, can you also let me know what's wrong so that I can learn from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Contains` method:

```
var o = Orders.Where(m => m.ProductID > 200 && 
                          m.CategoryID > 500 &&
                          CachedOrderIDs.Contains(m.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
var o = Orders.Where(m => m.ProductID > 200 && 
                          m.CategoryID > 500 &&
                          CachedOrderIDs.Contains(m.Guid)
             ).ToList();
```